# I am trying to check that two string are not equal using Specflow

Tags: specflow

I'm trying to compare two strings using this code in a switch statement:

```
case "medStepOne":
WebEligibilityMedFirst.SelectOptions(p0);
    if (!p0.Equals("failOne") || !p0.Equals("failTwo") || !p0.Equals("failThree") || !p0.Equals("failFour"))
       {
           WebEligibilityMedSecond.SelectOptions(p0);
        }
break;
```

The string is definitely "failOne" so I believe that the code should bypass the if statement but it does not.

Answer (score 0):

Embarrassingly, I saw the problem pretty much as soon as I'd re-read it to make sure I'd asked it correctly.  I need && instead of ||

Answer (score 0):

t appears that the issue is with the way the `if` condition is written. The condition `!p0.Equals("failOne") || !p0.Equals("failTwo") || !p0.Equals("failThree") || !p0.Equals("failFour")` is always true, even when the value of `p0` is "failOne".

You can modify the condition as follows to achieve the expected behavior:

```
if (!p0.Equals("failOne") && !p0.Equals("failTwo") && !p0.Equals("failThree") && !p0.Equals("failFour"))
{
    WebEligibilityMedSecond.SelectOptions(p0);
}
```

This condition will evaluate to true only if `p0` is not equal to "failOne", "failTwo", "failThree", or "failFour".